# Two squares in the unit square

Tags: computational-geometry

A square of side one contains two squares of sides $a$ and $b$ having non-overlapping interiors. How to prove the inequality $a+b≤1$ with Mathematica?
The same question in three dimensions and higher dimensions.

Here is my attempt. The squares are defined as
`ra = RotationTransform[ Rectangle[{c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2}, {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2}], \[Theta]1]`
and
`rb = RotationTransform[ Rectangle[{d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2}, {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2}], \[Theta]2]`.
Then I'd like to `Maximize` or `NMaximize` the objective function  `a+b` over `a,b,c1,c2,d1,d2, , \[Theta]2`, but I face the problems with the restrictions:
how to write down these are subsets of `Rectangle[]` and the non-overlapping of the square interiors in WL.

Addition. I am working  with it. As I understand now , it should be something like `ra[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,c1_?NumericQ,c2_?NumericQ,d1_?NumericQ,d2_?NumericQ,\[Theta]1_?NumericQ] := Rotate[ Rectangle[{c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2}, {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2}], \[Theta]1]` etc.

Comment: It seems that `rb = RotationTransform[ Rectangle[{d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2}, {d1 + a/2, d2 + a/2}], \[Theta]2]` should be `rb = RotationTransform[ Rectangle[{d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2}, {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2}], \[Theta]2]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a computer assisted proof. I do not know how to make it fully automatic.

**Lemma**
A square of unit length inside the first quadrant with center in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ contains the point (1,1).

∎
Without loss of generality consider a square that touches the $x$- and $y$-axes such as shown below. Let the angle be $\phi$ as defined in the figure.

```
w = 10 Degree;
SquareC = {1/2 (Sin[w] + 1), 1/2 (Sin[w] + 1)};
SquareTopLeft = {0, Cos[w]};
SquareBottomLeft = {Sin[w], 0};
SquareTopRight = {Cos[w], Cos[w] + Sin[w]};
SquareBottomRight = {Cos[w] + Sin[w], Sin[w]};
Origin = {0, 0};
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[],
  LightRed, Opacity[0.5], 
  Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[], w], {1/2 Sin[w], 1/2 Sin[w]}],
  Opacity[1], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[SquareC],
  Black, Point[{1, 1}],
  InfiniteLine[{SquareTopRight, SquareBottomRight}], 
  Text["(1,1)", {0.95, 0.95}], Gray, 
  Point[{SquareTopRight, SquareBottomRight}],
  Blue, InfiniteLine[{SquareBottomLeft, SquareBottomRight}],
  InfiniteLine[{Origin, SquareBottomLeft}], 
  Circle[Origin, 0.8, {-0.2 w, 1.2 w}],
  Text["\[Phi]", {0.85, 0.05}]
  }]
```

[image]

The equation of the line passing through its two corners reads
$$
(y-\sin\phi)=-\frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}(x-\sin\phi-\cos\phi).
$$
Let us substitute $x=1$ and verify that $y>1$ (if this is true for all angles $\phi$ the $(1,1)$ point is always covered by the square):

```
Reduce[(Sin[f]^2 - Cos[f] (1 - Cos[f] - Sin[f]))/Sin[f] >= 1 && Pi/2 > f > 0]
```

$$0<\phi<\frac{\pi }{2}.$$

This is the only place where MA was needed. In the remaining part, MA is only used to illustrate the proof.
∎

∎ Now the remaining proof consists of four steps. Let us conduct the proof for each fixed size of a bigger square $k=a$. In view of the lemma above, for $k=1/2$ we have $a+b\le 1$ for otherwise $(1/2,1/2)$ would be covered by both squares.

**I.** Let $k>1/2$ and larger square **A**  with size $a=k$ be in the left-bottom corner without loss of generality. Dark blue area denotes the possible position of its center. Light blue background denotes the considered unit square. The center of the second square **B** with size $b>1-k$ cannot be located in the red area for otherwise two squares will cover the $(k, k)$ point.

```
k = 0.6;
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[],
  Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {k, k}],
  EdgeForm[Directive[Red]], LightRed, Rectangle[{k, k}, {1, 1}],
  Black, Text[Style["A|a=k>1/2", 36], {k/2, k/2}]}]
```

[image]
 <sup>*Step I: center of B cannot lie in the top-right square*</sup>

**II.** By the same argument two other red squares cannot hold the center of **B** with size $b>1-k$. Thus, there are only 2 possibilities left. One of them is depicted and marked as green. It is sufficient to consider only one, the other one can be treated analogously.

```
k = 0.6;
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[],
  Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {k, k}],
  LightRed, EdgeForm[Directive[Red]], Rectangle[{k, k}, {1, 1}], 
  Rectangle[{1, 2 k - 1}, {k, k}], Rectangle[{2 k - 1, 1}, {k, k}], 
  EdgeForm[Green],
  LightGreen, Rectangle[{k, 0}, {1, 2 k - 1}],
  Black, Text[Style["A|a=k>1/2", 36], {k/2, k/2}], 
  Text[Style["B|b>1-k", 36], {(1 + k)/2, (2 k - 1)/2}]}]
```

[image]
 <sup>*Step II: two more areas can be eliminated*</sup>

**III.** If the center of **B** lies in the green area, the center of **A** cannot lie in the top left square (red).

```
k = 0.6;
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[],
  EdgeForm[Green], LightGreen, Rectangle[{k, 0}, {1, 1 - k}],
  LightRed, EdgeForm[Directive[Red]], Rectangle[{0, 1 - k}, {k, 1}],
  Black, Text[Style["B|b>1-k", 36], {(1 + k)/2, (1 - k)/2}]}]
```

[image]
 <sup>*Step III: reverse the argument, eliminate an area for A*</sup>

**IV.** The only configuration which supports $a+b > 1$ is shown below:

```
k = 0.6;
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[],
  EdgeForm[Green], LightGreen, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {k, 1 - k}], 
  Rectangle[{k, 0}, {1, 1 - k}],
  Black, Text[Style["A|a\[LessEqual]1-k", 36], {k/2, (1 - k)/2}], 
  Text[Style["B|b>1-k", 36], {(1 + k)/2, (1 - k)/2}],
  Red, Text[Style["Contradiction", 21], {1/2, 1/2}]}]
```

[image]
 <sup>*Step IV: Both centers must lie in the lower part of the unit square.*</sup>

However, it contradicts the initial assumption. Thus
$$
a+b \le 1
$$
as requested. ∎

Comment: The first place I don't understand is " Without loss of generality consider a square that touches the $x$- and $y$-axes such as shown below". Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494 if a unit square with center in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ can be found such that it does not cover $(1,1)$ and does not touch $x$, $y$-axes then we can translate it (first along $x$ and then along $y$) so that it touches axes. By this process $(1,1)$ will still remain uncovered. Thus, if a square violates the Lemma, it would be possible to find it among squares that touch $x$, $y$-axes.

Comment: Sorry, this is not serious. I'll be waiting for reach-in-content answers. I also think about it.

Comment: @user64494 Why is it not serious? Of course, it is not a numerical minimization proof as you requested. But even if it is possible, I doubt that such a numerical proof would be seriously accepted by mathematical community. The only known to me numerical proof of this kind is the Tomas Hales proof of the [Kepler conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture). Here, since a simple proof (in 2D) can be given, I doubt that there is a need for numerical minimization. For higher dimensions the question might still be open, I don't know.

Comment: @user64494 I actually have a shorter proof of your inequality in 2D. It is based on the same idea, relies on the covering property of the (1,1) point, but replaces steps II-IV with some other considerations. Are you interested?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Here is my attempt to anser the question.
First, we define two squares by

```
ra[a_?NumericQ, c1_?NumericQ, c2_?NumericQ, \[Theta]1_?NumericQ] := 
RegionConvert[ TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2}, {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2}],
RotationTransform[\[Theta]1]], "Implicit"];
rb[b_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ, \[Theta]2_?NumericQ] := 
RegionConvert[ TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2}, {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2}],
RotationTransform[\[Theta]2]], "Implicit"];
```

Second, we write down the condition of non-overlapping the squares as

```
RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[ra[a, c1, c2,\[Theta]1],rb[b, d1, d2, \[Theta]2]], 2] == 0
```

and the the conditions that the squares are subsets of the unit square as all 8 vertices belong to the unit square, for example, `(RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] <=  1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] <=  1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] >=  0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] >= 0` etc.

Now i try an approximate solution of the problem, allowing a small intersection, with low accuracy and precision.

```
NMaximize[{a + b,   RegionMeasure[ RegionIntersection[ra[a, c1, c2, \[Theta]1], 
  rb[b, d1, d2, \[Theta]2]], 2] <= 0.01 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
  c1 >= 0 && c2 >= 0 && d1 >= 0 && d2 >= 0 && c1 <= 1 && c2 <= 1 && 
  d1 <= 1 && d2 <= 1 && a <= 1 &&  b <= 1 && \[Theta]1 >= 0 && \[Theta]1 <= Pi/2 && 
\[Theta]2 >=  0 && \[Theta]2 <=  Pi/2 &&
(RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[1]] <=
 1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 - a/2, c2 - a/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]1] . {c1 + a/2, c2 + a/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 - b/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 - b/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 - b/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 - b/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 - b/2, d2 - b/2})[[2]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[1]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[2]] <= 
1 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[1]] >= 
0 && (RotationMatrix[\[Theta]2] . {d1 + b/2, d2 + b/2})[[2]] >= 
0}, {a, b, c1, c2, d1, d2, \[Theta]1, \[Theta]2}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, Method -> {"RandomSearch", 
"SearchPoints" -> 10,   
 "InitialPoints" -> {{1/10, 1/10, 1/4, 3/8, 1/4, 7/8, 0,  Pi/6}, 
{1/10, 1/10, 1/4, 3/8, 1/2, 7/8, 0, 0}}}]
```

Unfortunately, executing it, I obtain an error

> RegionMeasure::reg: RegionIntersection[ra[a,c1,c2,[Theta]1],rb[b,d1,d2,[Theta]2]] is not a correctly specified region.

which I don't understand since

```
Region[RegionIntersection[ra[1/4, 0, 0, 0], rb[1/4, 1/8, 0, Pi/4]]]
```

results in

[image]

Additionally, after that message the code is running without any result for hours.

Constructive suggestions are welcome.

Edit. Typos in the definition of `rb`: `b` instead of `a` and `\[Theta]2 instead of` [Theta]1` .